# Responsive images with custom image size

Tags: posts, customization

In a custom template, i'd like to have the images to be responsive.

I'm using the following code to achieve this:

```
wp_get_attachment_image($imageID, $size, false, array( 'class' => 'lazyload image-100p', 'data-sizes' => 'auto' ) );
```

The problem now is that the srcset and the sizes are only containing one image size.

[image]

Now my question is how to get the other breakpoints into it.

Kind regards

M.

Comment: Just use CSS file.

Comment: google page speed says: NO ;)

Comment: Really google says not to use a css file at all ? Come on :)

Comment: hahah google page speed says "no" to img {display:block; widht:100%;} :P